# Given the following regular language, what is the NFA?

Tags: nfa

```
(01)*01(0|1)*
```

What I'm seeing here is "at least one 01, followed by 0 or more 0's or 1's".

[image: Machine]

Am I over simplifying this, or just being paranoid that the expression looks a lot more complex than the drawn machine?

Comment: Your written description looks right to me, but it doesn't match your automata. It's at least one 01, yes, but it could be more and your graph doesn't account for that directly. I'm not sure if that's an issue though, since you can output any binary that starts with 01

Comment: @Decency I wondered about the necessity of accounting for more than one 01's on the graph too--0101 could be two 01's or just 01 followed by a random 0 and a random 1. Is that distinction necessary? But if that's not an issue, is the graph correct?

Comment: I would be explicit, personally, but either way seems correct to me. It's been a few years though.

Comment: Your solution is correct.  The regex could have been 01(0|1)* .

Comment: @Gene, that should be an answer.